# Knowing inside a leaveEvent which QWidget is entered

Tags: c++, qt

I'm implementing a QDialog which shows up when another QWidget (a QFrame) is hovered and destroyed when the mouse cursor leaves the QFrame. I do the construction and destruction via the enterEvent and leaveEvent (inside the QFrame):

```
void Frame::enterEvent(QEvent *) {
    m_dialog = new Dialog(this);
}

void Frame::leaveEvent(QEvent *) {
    m_dialog->deleteLater();
}
```

The dialog moves itself right below the frame when it's constructed. So far so good, but the mouse cursor also has to be able to go to the dialog. I thought about using underMouse() like so:

```
void Frame::leaveEvent(QEvent *) {
    if (! m_dialog->underMouse()) {
        m_dialog->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

but the problem is that inside Frame::leaveEvent, m_dialog->underMouse() is always false, even if the mouse is moved right onto it.

How can I know, inside Frame::leaveEvent, if the mouse is now on the dialog or somewhere else?

Comment: I think you need to handle the `QWidget::enterEvent()` in your dialog and not in the `Frame` class.

Comment: You may want to try to create a timer that will be triggered shortly after in the dialog, and there you can check whether the dialog should be closed, and if so, close it from there.

Comment: @vahancho: The dialog does not exist as long as it's created by Frame::enterEvent (it appears when the Frame is entered) ... so I can't use it before it exists ...

Comment: @Photon: That could probably work! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @TobiasLeupold, if your code resides inside of your Dialog class, it will not execute anyways if the dialog does not exist.

Comment: @Photon: Using a null timer that calls a function inside the Dialog which checks underMouse() and then decides if or if not to deleteLater() did the trick. Tanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could implement it in the following way:

The dialog's leaveEvent triggers a zero timer calling a function in the "target" widget (the widget where the cursor can go without the dialog being destroyed). This function checks if this widget is currently under the mouse cursor. If so, nothing happens. If not, the dialog is destroyed by that widget.

Same for the leaveEvent of the "target" widget, which calls a function implemented in the same way inside the dialog by a zero timer.